# how to increment sql counter in select query

Tags: sql, oracle

i want create a column 'counter' which will increase count whenever we run the select statement.

Suppose when i run the select query today. My output will be like below.

```
name    | employeeid | counter

raj        123             1
steve      124             1
brad       125             1
```

Tomorrow when i run the query the counter should gets increased for old records

```
name    | employeeid | counter

raj        123             2
steve      124             2
brad       125             2
pitt       126             1
```

on the 3rd day when i run the counter should gets increased for old records like above.

```
name    | employeeid | counter

raj        123             3
steve      124             3
brad       125             3
pitt       126             2
camie      127             1
```

select name, employeeid, count(name) over (partition by name) counter from mytable orded by doj desc

Comment: A SELECT doesn't update table data.

Comment: Do you have a separate record for each day for each name ?

Comment: what if you run select statement twice in a single day?

Comment: yes each records will gets added for each day (mostly) and sometimes two or more records gets added on particular day. And sometimes no records get added.

Comment: select statement runs once a day only @Pirate

Comment: @jarlh i know in update table we can do.. but i dont't have write access so with read access i am thinking if this can be achieved in select

Comment: you may need store procedure for this purpose , first this will fire update statement which will increase your counter by one and then execute select command

Comment: So your counter is basically number of days between creation of the record and today + 1. Does your table have creation date column or something similar?

Comment: @Marcin yes i have a creation date column for each record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're assuming that the query is executed once a day, then your counter is basically number of days between creation of the record and today + 1. Let's say the creation date is stored in creation_date column. You probably need something like:

```
select name, employeeid, 
       trunc(sysdate - creation_date) + 1 counter 
from your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you have to use trigger but the problem is that you can't use trigger on `select` statement.

But it could be achieve by using handler a PL/SQL procedure – that will process the Select Events that we want to be triggered on, then we can define a Fine Grained Auditing Policy that is associated with our Handler.

Reference : [Click here](https://technology.amis.nl/2005/09/26/select-trigger-in-oracle-database-introducing-fine-grained-auditing/)

Hope it will help.